# Which one is more appropriate, "only loves baseball" or "loves only baseball"?

Tags: word-choice, expressions

I asked a [question](http://the%20guy%20only%20loves%20baseball%20in%20the%20scope%20of%20available%20options.) just now.

I am not sure if this sentence is grammatical and idiomatic.

> the guy only loves baseball in the scope of available options.

Is this case, which one is more appropriate, "only loves baseball" or "loves only baseball"?

Answer (score 1):

*only* is a magical word, and it has the ability to change the meaning of a sentence by its placement.

in written English, “only” is put as close as possible to the word or phrase it modifies.

Check this:

> The new software only confused the secretary

...means the new software only confused her; it does not make her angry

> Only the new software confused the secretary

...means she is okay with rest all tools except the new software.

More examples of *placement* of 'only' are [fun to read here.](https://onlinewritingtraining.com.au/2018/07/29/only-position-in-a-sentence/)

So,

> the guy ***only loves*** baseball

...means the guy only loves it, he may not prefer playing it (though I *love X* sport may also mean that you love *playing* it. But it is just to make you understand)!

On the other hand,

> the guy loves ***only baseball***

...means he does not like any other sport.

Comment: You could also add '*The new software confused **only** the secretary*' meaning they were the only one confused by it.